# Angular Reactive Form - Error message for form control in array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have a simple reactive form in Angular with the fields using `FormArray`. I am getting the error status perfectly as "INVALID" for the dynamic field, but not getting the error for the control in `FormArray` and am unable to show the error message.

Can anyone help me to display them as well, please? For the standard field, I am getting my error, in fact it is able to be displayed in the browser.

The .ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder,FormArray, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
   regForm!:FormGroup;
  constructor(private fB:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.regForm=this.fB.group({
      fname:['',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(4)]],
      mail:[''],
      pwd:[''],
      altMail:this.fB.array([])
   });
  }

  get altMail()
  {
    return this.regForm.get('altMail') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewMail()
  {
     this.altMail.push(this.fB.control('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(10)]))
  }

  removeMail(i:number)
  {
    this.altMail.removeAt(i)
  }
  regDataSubmit()
  {
    // alert("Data submitted successfully");
    console.log(this.regForm.controls);
     console.log(this.regForm.value);
  }

}
```

The HTML file:

```
<form [formGroup]="regForm" (ngSubmit)="regDataSubmit()">

    <label for="fname">Firstname: </label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" formControlName="fname"><br><br>
    <div *ngIf="regForm.get('fname')?.touched">
        <div *ngIf="regForm.get('fname')?.hasError('required')">required</div>
        <div *ngIf="regForm.get('fname')?.hasError('maxlength')">maxlength 4</div>
    </div> 

    <label for="mail">Email: </label>
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" formControlName="mail"><br><br>

    <button (click)="addNewMail()">Add new Email</button><br><br>

    <div formArrayName="altMail" *ngFor="let input of altMail.controls;let i=index">
        <br>
        <input type="email" [formControlName]="i">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button (click)=" removeMail(i)"> Remove </button>
        <div *ngIf="regForm.get('i')?.touched">
            <div *ngIf="regForm.get('i')?.hasError('required')">required</div>
            <div *ngIf="regForm.get('i')?.hasError('minlength')">minlength 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>


    <label for="pwd">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" formControlName="pwd"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the form control from `altMail` `FormArray` instead of the `regForm` `FormGroup` (root).

```js
altMail.get(i)
```

```
<div *ngIf="altMail.get(i)?.touched">
  <div *ngIf="altMail.get(i)?.hasError('required')">
    required
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="altMail.get(i)?.hasError('minlength')">
    minlength 5
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrprdg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks. one more doubt, Why are you converting it to string by toString()?

Comment: I updated my answer. Anyway, `.toString()` is not required, you can straight provide the number value.